# How to find the date of the last lowest/highest value in Excel?

Tags: excel

For example, if I am looking at the 10yr treasury rates from 2017, how do I find the date that last had an interest rate lower than `2.40` on than Dec 29, 2017?  The date in this case is on Dec 18, 2017 at `2.39`.   See link below.

https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldYear&year=2017

I tried a few index with match functions from other threads, but I could not get the right number. It seems to pick from a random lower number in the middle of the list or it shows `#N/A` or `#VALUE!`.

Things I've tried.

```
=INDEX(A:J,MATCH(D251,J:J,1),1)
```

---

```
=INDEX(J:J,MATCH(MIN(ABS(J:J-J251)),ABS(J:J-J251),0))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the value:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($J$2:$J$251<$J$251),$J$2:$J$251)
```

To get the associated date (make sure to format the cell as a date):

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($J$2:$J$251<$J$251),$A$2:$A$251)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($2:$251)/(J$2:J$251<2.4), 1))
```

You will initially return a number like 43087. Format as date.